# How to stop images from becoming blurry in bootstrap responsive design ?/

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

the `bootstrap-responsive.css` adds `max-width:100%` to all `.img` tags.  Because of this my images are getting blurr. If i remove this the images are super clear but not responsive anymore. Is there a way i can have responsive images (i.e resize on their own) and still have them clear and not blurry

Comment: optimize your images with photoshop and than use

Comment: could you provide some code to help us understand your situation? 
The max-width should not have anything to do with the default size of the images

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the max-width setting by adding a class to your images that you do not want to re-size when scaling the browser.

```
    .fixed_width {
      height: 32px;
      width: 32px;
      max-height: 32px;
      max-width: 32px;
     }

    <img class="fixed_width" alt="{{item.Name}}" ng-src="Images/{{item.ImageUrl}}" />
```

Comment: this has a little angular I presume ?

Comment: Here also we are fixing the width, hence making it non-responsive?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by placing a max-width on the outer container of the image to the images dimensions.

```
.outer-image-container { 
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

The HTML would be as follows:

```
<div class="outer-image-container">
     <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps a bit. It keeps my image responsive without blurring it out.

Comment: if the width is fixed, then it wont be responsive anymore, no?